# PLSQL Search with VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with a column called `BARCODE` (`VARCHAR2`); it has one record with the value of `CORE-BARCODE1`.

When I run the following PL/SQL statement:

```
declare
    num_lines INT;
begin
    SELECT COUNT (*) into num_lines
        FROM CORE.SAMPLE s
       WHERE s.barcode = 'BARCODE1';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(num_lines));
end;
```

As expected a zero is printed out; however if I modify this to include a var to search as shown:

```
declare
    num_lines INT;
    barcode varchar2(56);
begin
    barcode := 'BARCODE1';
    SELECT COUNT (*) into num_lines
        FROM CORE.SAMPLE s
       WHERE s.barcode = barcode;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(num_lines));
end;
```

This prints out a 1 but this is wrong; why it giving me back a 1 when I use a variable (Which is clearly wrong)?

Thanks.

Comment: OK I changed the name of the variable to xx and it worked - however I still don't understand why that happens?

Comment: Possibly because `s.barcode = barcode` is effectively comparing the column to itself, as opposed to your `varchar2` variable?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't name variables the same name as a column.  Some folks like to just prepend "v_" to the front to differentiate the variable from the column.

Comment: A bit more explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28860611/266304); not quite sure the question is a duplicate but same issue.

Comment: I think that it is what you say that some kind of hungarian notation thing is solving it and I agree that it is comparing it to the column

Answer (score 3):

By changing the variable name to xx it worked because previosuly the query was like below

```
Select count (*) into num_line
from core.sample s
where 1=1
```

Just like `1=1` the condition `s.barcode= barcode` is true for all rows. If you add more rows to table you will get total row count with condition `s.barcode=barcode`