# Oracle - Get function parameter value in cursor

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, parameters, cursor

I have a package where I have created one function like this

```
create or replace package pk_server_control
is
function fn_get_employees_by_consultant(consultant_id number) return number;
end;
-----------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace package body pk_server_control
is

 **function fn_get_employees_by_consultant(consultant_id number)
 return number
 is
  cursor employees is select c.CST_NAME, a.NO_OF_EMPLOYEES from NISHAN_LDS_ACCOUNT a join NISHAN_LDS_CONSULTANT c
                      on c.CONSULTANT_ID = a.FK1_CONSULTANT_ID where c.CONSULTANT_ID =consultant_id ;
 total number := 0; **

 begin
   for data in employees
   loop
    total := total + data.NO_OF_EMPLOYEES;
   end loop;

   return total;
 end;
end;


begin
dbms_output.put_line(pk_server_control.fn_get_employees_by_consultant(1));
end;
```

I need to get value from the parameter "consultant_id number" of function "fn_get_employees_by_consultant" into "consultant_id" of the cursor "". While running, it doesn't give an error also it doesn't pass the value. Please help me to get through this :)

Comment: Did you add `consultant_id` to the `select` list of the cursor?

Comment: By "doesn't pass the value" do you mean you get no results, or too many, or something else? It looks like a simple name clash, which would return all rows from your table... [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860611/266304) for instance. (Possibly a duplicate?)

Comment: Unrelated, can i point out that you can do this directly in SQL with SUM, rather than a loop. Row-by-row is slow-by-slow.

Comment: It doesnot pass any results.

Comment: So your block prints zero - or nothing? What do you see if you run the cursor query manually, both exactly as you have it and with the last variable changed to a literal 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
create or replace package pk_server_control
is
 function fn_get_employees_by_consultant(consultant_id number) return number;
end;
-----------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace package body pk_server_control
is
  function fn_get_employees_by_consultant(consultant_id number)
  return number
  is
   val number := consultant_id;
   cursor employees is select c.CST_NAME, a.NO_OF_EMPLOYEES from NISHAN_LDS_ACCOUNT a join NISHAN_LDS_CONSULTANT c
                       on c.CONSULTANT_ID = a.FK1_CONSULTANT_ID where c.CONSULTANT_ID =val;
  total number := 0;

  begin
    for data in employees 
    loop
     total := total + data.NO_OF_EMPLOYEES;
    end loop;

    return total;
  end;
end;


begin
 dbms_output.put_line(pk_server_control.fn_get_employees_by_consultant(3));
end;
```