# Cursor returns 0 as count even though there are values available in table for the mentioned query in the cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have created a function to find duplicate entries in a table. Cursor in the function always returns 0 even though there are duplicates in the table. We are able to get the exact duplicate count by executing the query but when we use the same query in cursor, it behaves in a different manner.

We have tried executing the query. it gives the expected result but it behaves in a different way when incorporated with a function.

```
 create or replace function PL_DEV(dev_level in varchar2, remarks in 
 varchar2,wi_name in varchar2)    
 return number    
 is     
 resp number(8); 
 records number(10);



    CURSOR RECORDS_INFO
 IS
 select count(WI_NAME) as reccount from PL_AUTO_DEV_GRID where  
 DEV_LEVEL=dev_level and REMARKS_MITIGANTS=remarks and WI_NAME=wi_name;

 RECORDS_INFO_OBJ RECORDS_INFO%ROWTYPE;
 begin    
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('dev_level=='||dev_level||'');
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('remarks=='||remarks||'');
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('wi_name=='||wi_name||'');

 OPEN RECORDS_INFO;

 FETCH RECORDS_INFO INTO RECORDS_INFO_OBJ;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count from db=='||RECORDS_INFO_OBJ.reccount||'');
     records:=RECORDS_INFO_OBJ.reccount;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('records=='||records||'');
 CLOSE RECORDS_INFO;

 if records=0 then
 resp:=0;
 end if;
 if records!=0 then
 resp:=1;
 end if;

 return resp;    
 end;
```

Expected Result: Exact Count

Actual Result: 0

Comment: `DEV_LEVEL=dev_level ... and WI_NAME=wi_name` works like `1=1`. Change parameter names like `p_dev_level`, `p_wi_name`.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28860190/266304) - though you should get the count of all records, not zero; unless one of the columns you're checking is always null maybe. Your question talks about looking for duplicates, but your code doesn't seem to be doing that - so is that your actual cursor query?

Comment: sorry @Alex. I failed to mention that the query is to find count of duplicates.

Comment: @Ponder Stibbons , Thank you so much. it is working now.