# ORA-00923 FROM key word is not specifed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I know this quesion has a lot of answers but to be honest i really can't found any fixes to my issue and i relly don't see what i am doing wrong.

I am trying to insert some data via a select and a few changes, but everytime i get this FROM keyword not found where excepted

I tried to qote it multiple times differently but it didn't worked as well i know my select "Normally" work.

```sql
exec :='INSERT INTO TALEND_CONTEXT_GROUP (PROJECT_ID,CONTEXT_NAME,CONTEXT_TYPE,CONTEXT_DESC,ENV_ID,DATE_CREATION,USER_CREATION)
SELECT PROJECT_ID, CONTEXT_NAME, CONTEXT_TYPE, CONTEXT_DESC, '||New_Env_Id||', '||Current_Date||',USER_CREATION 
FROM TALEND_CONTEXT_GROUP
WHERE PROJECT_ID = '||Project_Id||'';
```

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(exec) ;
```

Of course the 2 used variable in here are working and returns 2 numbers

I would want it to simply insert nearly the same data in the same table except changing the `ENV_ID` and the `DATE_CREATION`

Comment: *changing the ENV_ID and the DATE_CREATION* Change to what?

Comment: Well i meant that with my insert i need to input nearly the same data except that i want to change the ENV_ID (i have a variable for it) and the DATE_CREATION (i have also a variable one is called "New_Env_Id" and the second one "Current_Date"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a `,` in one of your numbers - better use bind then concatination:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TALEND_CONTEXT_GROUP (PROJECT_ID,CONTEXT_NAME,CONTEXT_TYPE,CONTEXT_DESC,ENV_ID,DATE_CREATION,USER_CREATION)
SELECT PROJECT_ID, CONTEXT_NAME, CONTEXT_TYPE, CONTEXT_DESC, :New_Env_Id, :CURRENT_DATE,USER_CREATION 
FROM TALEND_CONTEXT_GROUP
WHERE PROJECT_ID = :Project_Id' using New_Env_Id, CURRENT_DATE, Project_Id;
```

Then again why do you even use dynamic sql? Why not directly:

```
INSERT INTO TALEND_CONTEXT_GROUP (PROJECT_ID,CONTEXT_NAME,CONTEXT_TYPE,CONTEXT_DESC,ENV_ID,DATE_CREATION,USER_CREATION)
SELECT PROJECT_ID, CONTEXT_NAME, CONTEXT_TYPE, CONTEXT_DESC, New_Env_Id, CURRENT_DATE,USER_CREATION 
FROM TALEND_CONTEXT_GROUP
WHERE PROJECT_ID = Project_Id;
```

Comment: Oh damn if it works without dynamic SQL i will try ! Because it's a pain. Let me try right now and if it works i approve or continue the comments thanks for your answer!

Comment: Somehow the select isn't applied it create a copy of everything and not only of the project_ID i asked for

Comment: Do i need to do a variable conversion? But it's stored in number format

Comment: Oh no i am not i am using it in a if and like if i define the project ID manually it works and i get the project ID via a sql query. if i do a dbms output it shows correctly

Comment: I think it's possible that's its the fact that they are both called Project_Id one is simply all uppercase and the other (the variable) all lower case is it possible to correct it easily or should i better rename it?

Comment: Well it worked that's all i wanted thanks for your help !

Comment: @Poli - just for info, [old answer that refers to the name clash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860611/266304).

Comment: Problem is that `PROJECT_ID = Project_Id`is allways true since both names are the same, rename the variable and it will work...